# How can I fix "another instance of SomeApp is currently closing.." error message?

Tags: portable-apps

I just tried to open PuTTY Portable and got the following error:

[image: error message screenshot]

I have checked Task Manager and can't see that PuTTY Portable is running, despite what the message says. What could be going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the directory of where you installed your program. Then go to `Data`, there should be a file called `PortableApps.comLauncherRuntimeData-FeedNotifierPortable.ini` (with the name of your respective program after the dash). The Status was probably stopped or running (meaning the program was probably closed abnormally), change it to stopped, save & exit. Copy the path in the PluginsDir, then go to that path & you'll see another file `runtimedata.ini`, open it. Change the Status to stopped as well. Now open task manager & kill your respective application or do a reboot (to ensure its not running). Then try to launch normally :)